# SQL to convert a string to decimal where the last field is a negative identifier

Tags: sql

Could anyone help me with converting a string to a positive/negative decimal where the negative indicator is the last value in the field.  For example, i have '000000012-' and '000001902 '.  I need the first value to return -0.12 and the second to return 19.02, when i sum them i should get a sum of 18.90.

At this point i only know how to get the positive values to work using...

```
SELECT decimal(sum(decimal(mycolumn,10,2)/100),10,2) as Balance
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: Sorry - DB is DB2

Answer (score 2):

In Standard SQL, you can do something like this:

```
select sum(case when mycolumn like '%-'
                then - cast(replace(mycolumn, '-', '') as decimal(10, 2)) / 100.0
                else cast(mycolumn as decimal(10, 2)) / 100.0
            end)
```

This should work in most databases.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work - was over complicating it.  Answer below...

SELECT sum(substr(mycolumn,10,1)||decimal(decimal(substr(mycolumn,1,9),9,2)/100,9,2))
FROM mytable;

Comment: Beware that you are not substracting the negative values